# Text Editor on Egghead.io videos

Tags: text-editors, ide

Does anybody know what text editor is being used in the [egghead.io videos](http://egghead.io/). I was just hoping for the windows version which is used in the first atleast 2 videos.  Saying the mac one would be a bonus, but I really want the windows one.  (I'm thinking it's the same software for both though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text-editor name is displayed at the top of the program window in each video. Just to clarify, the text-editor or more accurately, the IDE (Integrated Development Environment) being used is called [Jetbrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).